# Numpy matrix sum without looping

Tags: python, numpy

Trying to build a numpy matrix without double for loops

if i have a matrix:

```
x = [val, val, val]
    [val, val, val]
    [val, val, val]
```

and I want to subtract each row's items with the other two rows while simultaneously extrapolating to a larger matrix with final result.  Each row substraction (in this example) is 3 elements.  (I'm doing it with larger matrices though)

```
new = [row 1 - 2,      0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
      [row 1 - 3,      0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
      [0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  row 2 - 1,     0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
      [0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  row 2 - 3,     0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
      [0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0  row 3 - 1]
      [0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0  row 3 - 2]
```

And then similar but with the columns instead except the items are filled in horizontally, if that makes sense (each item is a single value vs above)

```
new = [col 1 - 2, 0.0, 0.0, col 1 - 2, 0.0, 0.0, col 1 - 2, 0.0, 0.0]
      [col 1 - 3, 0.0, 0.0, col 1 - 3, 0.0, 0.0, col 1 - 3, 0.0, 0.0]
      [0.0, col 2 - 1, 0.0, 0.0, col 2 - 1, 0.0, 0.0, col 2 - 1, 0.0]
      [0.0, col 2 - 3, 0.0, 0.0, col 2 - 3, 0.0, 0.0, col 2 - 3, 0.0]
      [0.0, 0.0, col 3 - 1, 0.0, 0.0, col 3 - 1, 0.0, 0.0, col 3 - 1]
      [0.0, 0.0, col 3 - 2, 0.0, 0.0, col 3 - 2, 0.0, 0.0, col 3 - 2]
```

If someone has the numpy magic to figure this, I'll lose it ha.

Edit: better example with small matrix:

```
x = [[.5, 0.], 
     [.1, 1.2]]
```

turns into

```
new = [[ 0.4, -1.2,  0.,   0. ],
       [ 0.,   0.,  -0.4,  1.2]]
```

and for column version

```
y = [[.2, .9], 
     [.6, .1]]
```

turns into

```
new = [[-0.7,  0.,   0.5,  0. ],
       [ 0.,   0.7,  0.,  -0.5]]
```

Comment: Can you give an actual example that makes sense? With actual numbers, so it's clear what is happening? I'm not sure I understand your made up notation.

Comment: sure I'll use a 4 x 4 matrix

Comment: Thanks. Anything will do.

Comment: Hope that helps, I dont see any way around looping but the calculations take so long it would be great if numpy could do something.

Comment: That's quite clear now. Could you show what you've tried so far, so I could see which loop is tripping you up?

Comment: I'm doing it all manually via for loops, my numpy skills are not very strong.

Comment: Basically double nested loops through each row with second loop to ensure the other rows/columns are summed with the current.

Comment: You can certainly compute each block without any looping in numpy. I can't think of a way to assemble the result immediately without a loop, but if you preallocate zeros it should speed things up drastically. It's late here, so I'll post something after I've had some sleep and seen what you've done already.

Comment: I suspected as much from your description. Could you post it here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some indexing madness which I believe does what you are asking for:

```
>>> def magic(data):
...     n, m = data.shape
...     assert n==m
...     rows = np.zeros((n, n-1, n, n), data.dtype)
...     cols = np.zeros((n, n-1, n, n), data.dtype)
...     idx = np.argsort(np.identity(n), kind='mergesort', axis=1)
...     self = idx[:, -1] # should be just 0, 1, 2, 3, ...
...     other = idx[:, :-1]
...     rows[self, :, self, :] = data[:, None, :] - data[other[..., None], self]
...     cols[self, ..., self] = data.T[:, None, :] - data.T[other[..., None], self] 
...     return rows.reshape(-1, n*n), cols.reshape(-1, n*n)
... 
>>> magic(np.array([[.5,0], [.1,1.2]]))
(array([[ 0.4, -1.2,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. , -0.4,  1.2]]), array([[ 0.5,  0. , -1.1,  0. ],
       [ 0. , -0.5,  0. ,  1.1]]))
>>> magic(np.array([[.2,.9], [.6,.1]]))
(array([[-0.4,  0.8,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0.4, -0.8]]), array([[-0.7,  0. ,  0.5,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0.7,  0. , -0.5]]))
```

Comment: First part works for sure, trying to debug whats wrong with second part.  Awesome job though, I honestly wasn't sure it was possible. Use of 'self' threw me off at first since its a python keyword.

Comment: @MarkII Could you elaborate on what's wrong? It seems to me it gives your expected result in both test cases. Also - sorry for being pedantic - `self` is not a keyword it is just used by convention.

Comment: Nevermind, I'm an idiot.  I was overwriting my test matrix with a transpose version.  Like I said its late.  This is definitely correct answer.

Comment: @MarkII No worries, I'm a bit scatterbrained myself at times.

Comment: Again this is incredible,  I need to get better with numpy for sure.  I was 99% certain no chance.  Can't wait to implement and see change in computational time.